# change the key and value of json result using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have written a java script code that gives json data it look like this

```
[{"batery":"98"},{"batery":"97"},{"batery":"80"},{"batery":"75"}]
```

i need to change the above json result to

```
[{"y":98},{"y":97},{"y":80},{"y":75}]
```

how to do this using java script. can any one guide me plz.

Answer (score 0):

```
const actualArray=[{"batery":"98"},{"batery":"97"},{"batery":"80"},{"batery":"75"}];
   const after= actualArray.map(obj=>{
      return {"y":obj.batery};
    })
```